# How to use awk to print counter+1 if line does not match previous line

Tags: bash

I have been working in bash trying print text based on an input file.
My file contains the following text:

```
a
a
a
b
c
c
c
d
d
e
e
```

For each line that does not match the previous line, I want to add 1 to a counter and print the counter next to original entry. For lines that are equal, I would like to print the counter as is, like so:

```
a 1  
a 1  
a 1  
b 2  
c 3  
c 3  
c 3  
d 4  
d 4  
e 5  
e 5
```

I have tried the code below, but this only provides me with information for the lines that are equal to the previous lines and does not print the counter.

```
f=a
counter=1

awk '{ 
if ($0==f && NR>1) {print f, counter} {f=$0} ; 
next
elif ($0!=f && NR>1) 
{print f, ++counter} {f=$0}
}' file.txt
```

output:

```
a   
a   
c   
c   
d   
e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need

```
awk '
    $1 != prev {c++; prev=$1} 
    {print $0, c}
' file
```

On the first line of the file, both `prev` and `c` will be undefined. The `$1 != prev` test will be true. awk will treat undefined `c` as the  number zero in arithmetic context, so the `++` operator properly sets c to 1.

Two place you're going wrong:

- expecting to be able to share shell and awk variables. You can't that way
- syntax for the `if` command: you have way too many braces.

This is your code restructured so that it works:

```
awk -v f=a -v counter=1 '{
    if ($0==f && NR>1) {print f, counter; f=$0 ; next}
    if ($0!=f && NR>1) {print f, ++counter; f=$0}
}' file
```

But it's written in a non-idiomatic way, and is pretty repetitive.  Plus you need to know the first line of the file.